# Is there any way to change datatype of a field in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Actual variable is Long but while saving it to Firestore I accidentally converted it to String, now I cannot perform queries like whereGreaterThan, whereLessThan, orderBy etc on this String field

Comment: Re-write the document with a value of the proper type?

Comment: Yes. But I have more than 1million document already in firestore, its impossible to edit through Firebase console. Is there any programmatic way to achieve this I mean by writing a cloud function or by changing the Firestore DB rules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There isn't a way to magically change the data type. The easiest way will be to re-write all the documents that were saved as a string.

You could use something like the Python server libraries to do this, using Cloud Shell in the GCP Console.

Note, you can grab all the documents with the field set to a string by doing a filter for `>= ""`. This will get you every field that has a string with any value, as well as empty strings.

Comment: I am not familiar with Python or GCP could you please provide an example for this? Also is it possible to filter String field with >= "" in android?